# MVC Model Updating

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I have a Model which is a business layer class and I pass that to the view through the controller in the following manner:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var MyModel = MyDatabaseInstance.Listings.GetByID(id);                        
    return View(MyModel);      
}
```

In the control for the update I have the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
{
    try
    {
        // TODO: Add update logic here

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

What I really want is to be able to get back the model object that I have used during the initial binding. Is that possible? If I change the arguments of the edit as such:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Listing MyModel)
```

it complains that there is "No parameterless constructor defined for this object." and my model cannot have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: why can't you add a parameterless constructor to your model?

Comment: The reason is that the constructor takes a factory as argument which knows what database is used to store the object. If I add a parameterless constructor and hide it from everything else will this give me the exact object as I passed in the view?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you use a ViewModel rather than binding directly to the entity from your database.

Using a ViewModel has the following advantages (not exhaustive).

- Views often have specific requirements to how you display data.  If you use the model from your DB then your going to endup adding unnecessary properties to your model.
- Security, you don't want to expose properties on your model to automatic binding when posting back to the controller.
- Validation requirements may be different for your view than your entity model.
- Just easier to change a ViewModel if your presentation requirements change.